# Kubuntu 19.10 black screen after wake up

Tags: suspend, kubuntu, hibernate, sleep

I just got a new Laptop at work and installed a clean Kubuntu 19.10 on it. There is this problem: everytime I close the lid and reopen in or put it in sleep mode manually and attempt to wake it up, the screen stays black, just the LEDs on the keyboard will light up.

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T495 if that helps. I tried another fresh install but that did not work.

I also tried to find a solution already but nothing really worked.

Answer (score 0):

Add `amd_iommu=off` to the kernel parameters in grub.

https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/comments/eo847g/kubuntu_1910_black_screen_after_wake_up/

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contibution. Since external links can become invalid, or the linked content can change, please edit your post to include a summary of why your approach would solve the OPs problem, and how you concluded what the OPs problem actually is.